# Link help button to help File

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not a newbie to C# but I'm new in creating help files, I have created a help file using *HTML Help Workshop* and I have set the form Help button Property to true using:

```
    private void frmWelcome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.HelpButton = true;
    }
```

The Help button shows, but I want the help file shown when the help button is clicked.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Handle the form's HelpButtonClicked event, and launch the help file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -

[System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(Control, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.showhelp.aspx)

Here is an example of how to use it on click event:

```
//Event-Handler overloading
this.HelpBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.HelpBtn_Click);

//The Event-Handler declarion
private void HelpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Help.ShowHelp(this, "file://c:\\yourHelpFiles\\help.chm");
}
```

Comment: thanks but i knew how to do that, i was just wondering the event handler to put it but Blorgbeard comment has help